# sqlite3からmysqlに切り替える際、mysql2のインストールエラーが発生してしまう

Tags: ruby, mysql, bundler

#### 前提

ポートフォリオ作成のため、現在自作アプリを実装しております。
現在、本番環境での自動デプロイを実装するため、参考記事を確認していた所、DB環境がMySQLに設定されていることが前提の記事が多いと感じました。
そのため、以前はローカルでsqlite使用、本番でmysql使用と分けていたものを全ての環境でmysqlを使えるように設定したく実装を進めています。

#### 環境

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.1
macOS

#### エラー内容

色んなことを試したため、かなり長くなっておりますがお力いただければ幸いです。

```
hana_nav_app+[master] % bundle                                                        
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
・
・
Fetching mysql2 0.5.3
・
・
Using sass-rails 6.0.0
Installing mysql2 0.5.3 with native extensions
Using devise-i18n 1.10.0
Using rails 6.1.4.1
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/ext/mysql2
/Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20210921-50046-8t4gxa.rb extconf.rb --with-cppflags\=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
/Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `block in find_library': undefined method
`split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `collect'
        from /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:87:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-20/2.7.0/mysql2-0.5.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

#### 解決したいこと

mysql2をインストールさせたいです。

#### 試したこと

mysql@5.7を使用したいため、以前入れていたデータを全て削除しました。

```
brew remove mysql
brew cleanup

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/opt/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/my.cnf
```

次に`brew install mysql@5.7`でインストールを行い、mysqlのパスを通しました。
下記コードが現在の状況です。

```
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"
```

バージョンを確認、mysqlコマンドを使用できることを確認

```
~ % mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for osx10.16 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

gemを変更後、bundleインストール実行し、このときはエラーなく成功。mysqlサーバも起動しました。

```
Gemfile
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.3'

~ % mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
 SUCCESS! 
~ % 2021-09-20T11:43:31.6NZ mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

DBの定義ファイルを変更

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
 database: hana_nav_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
 database: hana_nav_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: hana_nav_app_production
```

DB作成時でエラーが発生しました。

```
hana_nav_app+[master] % bundle exec rails db:create
rails aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/taddy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/taddy/rails_projects/hana_nav_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
/Users/taddy/rails_projects/hana_nav_app/Rakefile:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:5:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

ググるとシンボリックリンクの問題とのことでした。

```
% bundle doctor

実行結果
Files exist in the Bundler home that are not readable/writable by the current user. These 
・ 文字数制限のため、省略
・
 * mysql2: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 * mysql2: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
```

`The following gems are missing OS dependencies:`以下に記述のあるgemをアンインストールしろとのことなので、まず最初にmysql2を削除しました。

```
hana_nav_app+[master] % bundle exec gem uninstall mysql2
Successfully uninstalled mysql2-0.5.3
```

無事アンインストールできたので再度確認した所、bundleインストールしてとのことなので実行。

```
hana_nav_app+[master] % bundle doctor                   
The following gems are missing
 * mysql2 (0.5.3)
Install missing gems with `bundle install`
```

実行後のエラー文が「エラー内容」になります。
この後、`gem install mysql2 -v '0.5.3'`も試したのですが駄目でした。

詳しい方がいましたらアドバイスいただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。